# Doesn't show zeros when I cast a varchar date sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
concat(concat(concat(concat('9635CLR', substring(cast(date_part('year',er.fecha_procesado) as varchar),3,4)),
substring(cast(date_part('month',er.fecha_procesado) as varchar),0,2),
substring(cast(date_part('day',er.fecha_procesado) as varchar),0,2),
r.digito_remesa)))
```

For example , the result of the query now is this:

```
9635CLR 21   9     7     502
        year month day
```

so what i want it would be this:

```
9635CLR 21   09    07     502
        year month day
```

Why SQL is ignoring the zeros?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  As for your question, integers have no leading zeros so there are none.

Comment: Is not possible do this with plain SQL? Anyway i'm using postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want dates in a particular format, use `to_char()`.  I would expect something like this:

```
('9635CLR' || ' ' ||
 to_char(er.fecha_procesado, 'YY MM DD') || ' ' ||
 r.digito_remesa
)
```

I'm not sure how the spacing between the values is being set, but you can add spaces as needed.